# material-ui TextField type number up/down arrows not appearing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I added TextField type='number' to my react component but up/down arrows are not appearing

```
<TextField type="number"  /> 
<TextField
          id="filled-number"
          label="Number"
          type="number"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          margin="normal"
          variant="filled"/>
```

Both are not working what can cause this?

Comment: when you hover with your mouse over the text field, or click it, do you see the arrows?

Comment: No, that is the problem

Comment: The code you posted is working, I can see the arrows. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-s0j0j?fontsize=14

Comment: Yes, the code is correct .I'm looking for the reason why it is not showing in my app

Comment: We need more code to find the problem. Because the code in the question is working, we can't know what the problem is. Try to reproduce the bug and upload to Code Sandbox

Comment: Thx for trying to help. The reason for this problem was css code of another component that override this code.